# Is it possible to run the RMI Registry as a daemon

Tags: java, rmi

Is it possible to run the RMI Registry on a daemon thread?  I'd like for it to shut down automatically when my unit tests are finished without calling a System.exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't 'run' at all, it is executed by the RMI Runtime on demand, so daemon threads dont come into it. You can unexport it like any other remote object.